# How do we plot magnitude-angle vector in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, vector

I am lost on how to plot this fairly simple vector with a magnitude and an angle in Mathematica. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

e.g. 20 @ 50 Degree Angle

Answer (score 7):

You can use the function [`AnglePath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnglePath.html):

```
{x, y} = {0, 0};
r = 20;
t = 50 Degree;
Graphics[{Red, Arrow @ AnglePath[{x, y}, {{r, t}}]}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [`AngleVector`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AngleVector.html):

```
Graphics[{Red, Arrow[{{x, y}, AngleVector[{r, t}]}]}]
```

> same picture

Answer (score 6):

With

```
{r, t} = {20, 50 Degree}
```

You can always make the vector mathematically with

```
vec = r {Cos@t, Sin@t}
```

and an illustrative example

```
With[
 {pt = r {Cos@t, Sin@t}(*Mathematical implementation of the vector*)},
 Graphics[
  {
   (*Make all the lines thick*) Thickness[.007],
   (*The arrow itself*){Arrow@{{0, 0}, pt}},
   (*Arc to show label the angle*) {Circle[{0, 0}, 5, {0, 50 Degree}]},
   (*Angle label*) {Text[Style[θ == 50 Degree, 15], 4 {0.85 Cos[t/2.5], 1.1 Sin[t/2.5]}]},
   (*Magnitude label*) {Text[Style["r = 20", 15], pt {0.9, 1}]}
   }
  ]
 ]
```

[image]