# Plotting a unit length line given its midpoint and an angle

Tags: plotting, graphics, random

I have generated random 3-tuples: $(x, y, \theta)$ where $\{x, y\}$ is the midpoint of a unit length line and $\theta$ is its angle with respect to the x-axis. Is there a way to plot these lines centered at their midpoints and with the angles indicated without doing any  formulaic manipulation?

The generated points are:

```
a =  RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, Pi}}],20];
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to plot line, from the origin to the center point given? or line of unit length from origin passing through the center point?  The title says to plot lines, but your question says to plot points.

Comment: @Nasser I'm trying to plot lines. Basically plotting AngleVector[{x, y}, $\theta$], but with $\{x, y\}$ as the middle point of the unit distance instead of the starting point.

Comment: may be you want [how-do-we-plot-magnitude-angle-vector-in-mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/228673/how-do-we-plot-magnitude-angle-vector-in-mathematica) ? it would have helped to include an image or link to what you wanted as an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this input form `AngleVector[{x, y}, {r, a}]`:

```
Graphics @ Replace[a,
    {x_, y_, angle_} :> Line[{
        AngleVector[{x, y}, {1/2, angle}],
        AngleVector[{x, y}, {-1/2, angle}]}
    ],
    {1}
]
```

Comment: Is there any way to change the color of those lines?

Answer (score 4):

Another way of doing this would be to generate and join two diametrically opposite points around a circle of radius `1/2` at each location while incorporating the angle with respect to the x-axis.

**Using `CirclePoints`:**

```
SeedRandom[1];
a = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, Pi}}], 
   20];
pts = CirclePoints[{#1, #2}, {1/2, #3}, 2] & @@@ a;

Graphics[{
  Black, AbsolutePointSize[6]
  , Point@a[[All, 1 ;; 2]]
  , Red, Line /@ pts
  , Blue, Dashed,  Circle[#, 1/2] & /@ a[[All, 1 ;; 2]]
  }
  , Frame -> True
  , AspectRatio -> 1
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
a = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, Pi}}], 
   20];
Graphics[{
  {Red, Line[AnglePath[{{#1, #2}, #3}, {{1/2, #3}}]]
     , Blue, Line[AnglePath[{{#1, #2}, π + #3}, {{1/2, #3}}]]
     , AbsolutePointSize[6], Black, Point[{#1, #2}]
     } & @@@ a[[1 ;; -1]]
  }
 , Frame -> True
 , AspectRatio -> 1
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Those lines don't seem to be a unit long.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

AngleVector[angle] gives a unit vector form the origin with an angle to the x axis. With this you may define a function that gives a line with a specified mid point and angle:

```
line[point_, angle_] := 
 Line[{point - 0.5 AngleVector[angle], 
   AngleVector[point - 0.5 AngleVector[angle], angle]}]
```

With this it is easy to draw slanted lines with given mid points. E.g. lines with fixed angles on a grid:

```
Graphics[
 Flatten[Table[line[{x, y}, Pi/4], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}], 1], 
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having issues trying to make this work with my random generator function: `a = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, Pi}}], 20];`

Comment: `line` requires the point to be a 2 element vector. You may either redefine `line` or use: `a = {#[[;; 2]], #[[3]]} & /@ a; Graphics[line @@@ a, Axes -> True]`